# Download file from ftp and decrypt it using jsftp and crypto in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, routes, ftp, cryptography

I'm actually doing a project where I have a ftp server, I want to be able to get a file from my computer, encrypt it and put it on ftp server. And also get the file from the ftp server, decrypt it and put it on my computer.

For the first step it worked succesfully :

```
router.post('/uploadftpobj', function(req, res) {
    let status = {
          status: 400,
          message: ''
    };
    let token = req.fields.idToken;
    let buffer = req.files.file;
    let filename = buffer.name.replace(/[^\w\-\.]/gi, '');

    ini.admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(async (decodedToken) => {
      if (!filename.endsWith(".obj")) {
        status.status = 400;
        status.message = "File must be a .obj !";
        res.send(status);
        return;
      }

      let data = fs.readFileSync(buffer._writeStream.path);
      let cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc',KeyCrypto);
      let crypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data),cipher.final()]);
      ftp_orthese_socket.put(crypted, "/obj_files/" + filename , err => {
              if (err) {
                  status.status = 400;
                  status.message = "File cannot be uploaded !";
                  res.send(status);
              } else {
                  status.status = 200;
                  status.message = "File has been uploaded !";
                  res.send(status);
              }
          })
      })
});
```

I got my encrypted file on my ftp server and everything is ok. But for the download step I don't succeed. Here's my code :

```
router.post('/downloadftpobj', function(req, res) {
  let status = {
    status: 200,
    message: 'The content of the file has been downloaded to the requested path !',
  };
  let token = req.fields.idToken;
  let user_path = req.fields.path;

  ini.admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(async (decodedToken) => {
    if (!user_path.endsWith(".obj")) {
      status.status = 400;
      status.message = "File must be an .obj !";
      res.send(status);
      return;
    }
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',KeyCrypto);
    var str = "";
    ftp_orthese_socket.get("/obj_files/" + user_path, (err, socket) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        socket.on("data", d => {
            str += d.toString();
        });
        console.log(str);
    });
  })
});
```

For the moment I tried to put the data of my file to a str but when I console.log(str) it's empty. I don't really see any solution, if you have any advice about anything else I'm listening ! :)

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a  little more detail about how you did the request? Was it through a form or a browser? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using postman and through a form-data I'm doing my requests